# Passing function argument to formula

Tags: r

I'm trying to understand why

```
foo = function(d,y,x) {
    fit = with(d, lm(y ~ x))
}
foo(myData, Y, X)
```

won't work, where for instance

```
myData = data.frame(Y=rnorm(50), X=runif(50))
```

The bit that seems tricky to me is passing the arguments `x` and `y` to a formula, as in `lm(y ~ x)`.

Comment: You could always do lm(mydata$Y ~ mydata$X)

Comment: @DMT, this is just a MWE; see https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 5, accepted):

@DMT's answer explains what's going on nicely.

Here are the hoops to jump through if you want things to work as you expect:

```
lmwrap <- function(d,y,x) {
    ys <- deparse(substitute(y))
    xs <- deparse(substitute(x))
    f <- reformulate(xs,response=ys)
    return(lm(f,data=d))
}
mydata <- data.frame(X=1:10,Y=rnorm(10))
lmwrap(mydata,Y, X)
```

Or it can be simplified a bit if you pass the column names as strings rather than symbols.

```
lmwrap <- function(d,y,x) {
    f <- reformulate(xs, response=ys)
    return(lm(f, data=d))
}
lmwrap(mydata, "Y", "X")
```

This approach will be a bit fragile, e.g. if you pass arguments through another function. Also, getting the "Call" part of the formula to read `Y~X` takes more trickery ...

Comment: I had also thought of something like `getfn<-function(x, y) { f<-eval(as.call(list(quote(`~`), substitute(x), substitute(y)))) ;environment(f)<-parent.frame(); f}` to make the formula. But I suppose that's pretty close to `reformulate()` would do, just skipping the stringification step. But until you posted this, I didn't know `reformulate()` existed.

Comment: seems one doesn't need `deparse()` for `y`, i.e., `ys <- substitute(y)` works as well. my criticism to DMT's answer was about it's generality, as it assumed I was concerned with `lm()` and `lm()` only, whereas the question is how to pass the arguments of the function `lmwrap` into a formula.

Comment: Would be better to just pass the formula directly? Like `lmwrap(y ~ x, d)`. I have no idea how to pass the `y~x` into `lm`, though. Would be very nice to hear some elaboration on that part.

Answer (score 0):

Y and X are your column names, not variables.   They wouldn't in this case, be arguments to your function unless you passed them in as strings and essentially call

```
lm(mydata[,"Y"]~ mydata[,"X"])
```

If you were to run ls() on your console, Y and X would most likely not be there, so the function won't work.  Print both x and y prior to the fit = call, and you'll likely see NULLs, which won't fly in lm.

One way to do this in your form is the following

```
lmwrap<-function(df, yname, xname){
fit=lm(d[,yname] ~ d[,xname])
}

lmwrap(mydata,"Y", "X")
```

But you could just make the lm call like regular

Comment: Yes it does, but when you wrap the call in a function, you now attempt to pass the "value" of Y to little y, and the "value" of X to little x.   y and x will take the value of the variables passed to them, which in your case is most likely null.  When making the with call in the global environment, you circumvent that value passing process occurring in your function, and R is able to bind Y with mydata$Y essentially, and the same for X.  Apologies if I'm not explaining it well

Comment: so your comment sort of explains why the function call fails; but it doesn't solve the problem of how to do this -- it surely can be done.

Comment: You can replicate your problem in the function by saying y=Y and x=X then calling with(mydata y~x)

Comment: "just make the `lm` regular call" -- that's not the point! I want to be able to pass two arguments -- here `y` and `x`into a formula -- and that's not necessarily for an `lm()`!!! that's what a MWE is supposed to do, and I signaled that in my question, and then in my comment again. say in `myData1` the variables of interest are `var1' and `var2`; and in `myData2` the variables are `A` and `B`. your answer doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: but @DMT **has** explained very clearly (IMO) what's going on, and the function they provide in their answer shows that if you're willing to put your variables in quotation marks everything can be made to work just fine.  (I agree that their final line isn't too useful.)